# Multilevel concatenation grouped by a common index (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to combine multiple dataframes into one. I need the combined dataframe to have multilevel headers, as in the example below. I also need the dataframe to be grouped on multiple index columns.

I've seen answers for some part of the above but not combined, and I can't figure it out.

I'd really appreciate some help!

edit: To clarify, I need the results to be grouped by index, when the indexes are not all listed in the same order.

'A'

```
                                   'a' 'b'  
'index4.1'  'index4.2'  'index4.3'  5   7
'index5.1'  'index5.2'  'index5.3'  3   8       
'index1.1'  'index1.2'  'index1.3'  9   8
'index2.1'  'index2.2'  'index2.3'  6   3
'index3.1'  'index3.2'  'index3.3'  8   4
'index4.1'  'index4.2'  'index4.3'  5   7
```

'B'

```
                                   'a' 'b' 
'index3.1'  'index3.2'  'index3.3'  1   5       
'index1.1'  'index1.2'  'index1.3'  6   2
'index2.1'  'index2.2'  'index2.3'  4   7
'index4.1'  'index4.2'  'index4.3'  4   7
'index5.1'  'index5.2'  'index5.3'  3   6
```

'C'

```
                                   'b' 'c'        
'index1.1'  'index1.2'  'index1.3'  3   0
'index3.1'  'index3.2'  'index3.3'  1   5
'index4.1'  'index4.2'  'index4.3'  6   7
'index5.1'  'index5.2'  'index5.3'  3   1 
'index2.1'  'index2.2'  'index2.3'  2   1
```

Combined dataframe:

```
                                   'A' 'A' 'B' 'B' 'C' 'C'
                                   'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c'      
'index1.1'  'index1.2'  'index1.3'  9   8   6   2   3   0
'index2.1'  'index2.2'  'index2.3'  6   3   4   7   2   1
'index3.1'  'index3.2'  'index3.3'  8   4   1   5   1   5
'index4.1'  'index4.2'  'index4.3'  5   7   4   7   6   7
'index5.1'  'index5.2'  'index5.3'  3   8   3   6   3   1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with `keys` parameter:

```
df = pd.concat([A, B, C], axis=1, keys=('A','B','C'))
print (df)
                                   A       B       C    
                                 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c'
'index1.1' 'index1.2' 'index1.3'   9   8   6   2   3   0
'index2.1' 'index2.2' 'index2.3'   6   3   4   7   2   1
'index3.1' 'index3.2' 'index3.3'   8   4   1   5   1   5
'index4.1' 'index4.2' 'index4.3'   5   7   4   7   6   7
'index5.1' 'index5.2' 'index5.3'   3   8   3   6   3   1
```

If need display first levels:

```
with pd.option_context("display.multi_sparse", False):
    print (df)
                                   A   A   B   B   C   C
                                 'a' 'b' 'a' 'b' 'b' 'c'
'index1.1' 'index1.2' 'index1.3'   9   8   6   2   3   0
'index2.1' 'index2.2' 'index2.3'   6   3   4   7   2   1
'index3.1' 'index3.2' 'index3.3'   8   4   1   5   1   5
'index4.1' 'index4.2' 'index4.3'   5   7   4   7   6   7
'index5.1' 'index5.2' 'index5.3'   3   8   3   6   3   1
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! This was the approach I was going for initially. However, if the indexes are not all listed in the same order, it doesn't appear to group by index. I've edited the original question to include this problem. Your solution seems to just stack each dataframe side by side.

Comment: @tomp - ya, index values are sorted, because for perfromance is necessary sorted MultiIndex